# Смена значения value в submit при адаптиве css

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени! Делаю адаптивное меню есть там одна кнопка типа `submit` вот:

```
 <input type="submit" class="gener" name="prlog" value=" ">
```

при десктопном разрешении на ней стоит бэкграунд картинка вот так:

```
.gener {
  width: 50px;
  height: 31px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent url(../img/login.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

по этому `value` у элемента пустое - но в мобильной версии при адаптиве к примеру на `480px` кнопка увеличивается и растягивается:

```
.gener {
  height: 100px;
  background: #3CAD5F url(../img/login.jpg) no-repeat right center;
  background-size: 100px 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

и нужно что бы в `value` было написано `"Вход"`, увы я не могу просто сменить бэкграунд со значка (в десктопной версии) на картинку с надписью вход, хотя это было бы идеальным решением, т.к. на сайте будут в дальнейшем многоязыковые версии и надписи будут выводиться из переменных.

Можно ли как то установить `value` элемента путем css? Очень не хочу вставлять костыли через javascript

Comment: > костыли через javascript

Comment: т.е. вы хотите сказать что выполнение таких простых задач через JS это костыль? Скорее костылем будет на CSS.

Comment: @Duoxx это бессмысленный спор. Задать value через css НЕВОЗМОЖНО.

Comment: @Duoxx все, что можно сделать с помощью css в данной ситуации - подменить один input другим, через display: none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен что это будет правильно, но:

```css
div{
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

div:before{
  content: attr(data-value);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 31px;
  border: none;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div data-value="login"><input type="submit"  value=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Через js лучше. А почему на JS это костыль объясните. https://jsfiddle.net/84m4vt7g/

```js
window.onresize = function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 700)
    $('.responsive').val('Вход')
}
  if (window.innerWidth < 700)
    $('.responsive').val('Вход')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="Войти" class="responsive" type="submit">
```